# error: no matching function for call to 'conjugate_gradient' in Eigen Library

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am getting following error while compiling c++ coding having Eigen library

> error: no matching function       for call to 'conjugate_gradient' in
>   Eigen Library

Here is the code below:

```
SparseMatrix<double> A(truncatedSize,truncatedSize);
for(int i=0;i<truncatedSize;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<truncatedSize;j++)
    {
        A.insert(i,j)=TruncatedGlMatrix[i][j];
    }
}

VectorXf V(truncatedSize);
for(int i=0;i<truncatedSize;i++)
{       
    V(i)=TruncatedForce[i][1];
}

// solve Ax = b
ConjugateGradient<SparseMatrix<double>, Lower|Upper> cg;
cg.compute(A);

VectorXf xa(truncatedSize);
xa = cg.solve(V);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to show this as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you had mocked it up a bit more, the following could have been your result:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    int truncatedSize = 50;
    SparseMatrix<double> A(truncatedSize, truncatedSize);

//  We have no idea what TruncatedGlMatrix or TruncatedForce are...
//  for (int i = 0; i < truncatedSize; i++)
//  {
//      for (int j = 0; j < truncatedSize; j++)
//      {
//          A.insert(i, j) = TruncatedGlMatrix[i][j];
//      }
//  }

    VectorXf V(truncatedSize);
//  for (int i = 0; i < truncatedSize; i++)
//  {
//      V(i) = TruncatedForce[i][1];
//  }

    // solve Ax = b
    ConjugateGradient<SparseMatrix<double>, Lower | Upper> cg;
    cg.compute(A);

    VectorXf xa(truncatedSize);
    xa = cg.solve(V);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a different error from you, but that may be because I had to add some guesswork as to what you're actually looking at. In the code above, the problem is that you're mixing `double` and `float` scalar types. Namely,

```
xa = cg.solve(V);
```

`xa` and `V` are vectors of `float`s, while `cg` and `A` have `double` as their scalar type. You must explicitly cast between these, so replacing that line with

```
xa = cg.solve(V.cast<double>()).cast<float>();
```

would solve the issue that my MCVE has (which might also be your problem, I don't know enough to tell).

Comment: yes! it works now. Problem lies on data type ( float and double ). I converted all vectors in double. And now it works fine.  Thanks for your input !